# setTimeout not working after update to jquery version 1.8.1

Tags: jquery, settimeout

hello i was using my long polling code from a long time it was working fine with jquery verison 1.8 but since i upgraded it to verison 1.8.1 it stopped working and its giving me the error

> Error: NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript
>   argument arg 0 [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]

this is my code

```
  (function pollfrnd() { setTimeout(function() { 
        var demon=$('.frndnotimore').val();
        var page="notirequest";
        var a=$('.gvpgvpxgvp').val();
        $.ajax({ url: 'modules/notifications/beast.php?nid='+demon+'&id='+a+'&page='+page, 
        success: function(html) {
        if ($.trim(html) == 'no')
        {

        }
        else
        {

        $('.frndnotimore').remove();
        $('.notiloadfriend').prepend($(html).fadeIn('slow'));
        counter(a,page);
        }
        }, dataType: "html", complete: pollfrnd }); }, 60000); })();

    });
```

Comment: Do none of the [results which come up for a search for that error](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS) lead you to a solution?

Comment: nope , i first tried it on google but still no help so i asked for help here

Comment: when you get data back from `beast.php` what does the HTML look like? Also, what does `counter(a,page)` do? any further DOM manipulations?

Comment: yes , the counter is for count of notifications . and html is like a normal html

Comment: the code works (albeit 404 errors) even if not connected to the internet, I am pretty sure his code is not the issue actually.

Comment: its not working with jquery 1.8.1 in firefox but its working with jquery 1.7 in firefox why?

Comment: Param just a wild guess (since I don't know what your code is really doing after you get the ajax) - in your code success callback you call $('.frndnotimore').remove(); but then it is needed again next time for $('.frndnotimore').val(); but it is not 100% clear if it is put back in DOM from your ajax response or not - is Firefox + New Jqueryversion choking on perhaps on this .frndnotimore element being missing from DOM while other browsers don't? dunno... I mean check if for some reason Firefox + neWJquery hates it if you are missing DOM elements or something like that

Comment: there is a `frndnotimore` present which is removed and ajax introduces new one

Comment: yes, and weird thing is - even in MY Firefox just now, with new Jquery 1.8.1, and even considering that I am not connected to internet (so my ajax doesn;t put it back) it STILL works with "undefined" and 404 error anyway - I still don't get nsiDOMERROR - so your code is OK anyway even on my test, with new Firefox, and new Jquery 1.8.1 - whats going on!!!! Try reinstall your firefox??? Whats your FFox version?

Comment: my firefox version is latest 14.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code exactly as below, I get no error at all actually(jquery 1.7.2 AND jquery 1.8.1 AND EVEN Firefox 14) and it even tries to poll something:

```
function pollfrnd() { setTimeout(function() { 
        var demon=$('.frndnotimore').val();
        var page="notirequest";
        var a=$('.gvpgvpxgvp').val();
        $.ajax({ url: 'modules/notifications/beast.php?nid='+demon+'&id='+a+'&page='+page, 
        success: function(html) {
        if ($.trim(html) == 'no')
        {

        }
        else
        {

        $('.frndnotimore').remove();

        $('.notiloadfriend').prepend(html);
        //This code below was your problem in Firefox
        //$('.notiloadfriend').prepend($(html).fadeIn('slow'));
        counter(a,page);
        }
        }, dataType: "html", complete: pollfrnd }); }, 60000); }

 pollfrnd();
```

Comment: Remember, use $('.notiloadfriend').prepend(html); not the animation one you had that said $('.notiloadfriend').prepend($(html).fadeIn('slow')); to avoid that strange error you described in your question that only happens in Firefox